# Is my use of "I was wondering" natural?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A cab driver drops a customer off at a house where there's a party.

Cab driver: *Hey, I was wondering, you need a ride home later? 'Cause if you do, I could just wait for you out here.*

Is my use of "I was wondering" completely natural?

Comment: yes, that's perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, people say that all the time. That is a very common phrase in the English language, and you will be totally ok using it.